# Elasticsearch : Cannot create a client node

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

I am trying to create a client node for my Elastic cluster, which has elasticsearch version 2.2.0. I have 4 nodes in my cluster and each of them can be data or master nodes. Now, i want to create a client node that will ping one of my other 4 nodes. My intention is that even if one of my 4 main nodes goes down, my client will be able to get data from some node that is functional.

Here is my elasticsearch.yml for client

```
cluster.name: myCluster
node.name: myClient
node.master: false
node.data: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["box1:9300","box2:9300","box3:9300","box4:9300"]
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
```

each of the above boxes are configured as

```
cluster.name: myCluster
node.name: n2
path.data: /asd/thth/jtjut/elastic
path.logs: /var/log/eslogs
network.host: box2
node.master: true
node.data: true
index.number_of_replicas: 1
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["box1:9300","box2:9300","box3:9300","box4:9300"]
discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout: 30s
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

action.disable_delete_all_indices: true

http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
```

but when i start the elasticsearch service on the client, i get

```
[2016-03-31 10:24:07,576][INFO ][discovery.zen            ] [myClient] failed
to send join request to master [{n2}{5vlJHDZaQhGttqZsD5gVvA}{34.87.98.213}{34.87.98.213:9300}{master=true}], reason [RemoteTransportException[[n2] 34.87.98.213:9300][internal:discovery/zen/join]]; nested:ConnectTransportException[[myClient][127.0.0.1:9300] connect_timeout[30s]]; nested: NotSerializableExceptionWrapper[Connection refused: /127.0.0.1:9300]; ]
```

why am i getting connection refused exception? is there anything missing from my configurations?

Comment: Can you try putting the client box - `box 5` also in the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: `

Comment: tried that, still the same error. are you suggesting putting box5 in all elasticsearch.yml files? including box1 to box4?

Comment: yes, please add it in all es.yml files.

Comment: thanks! that worked. now my client is up and running :)